# jQuery $(this) selector not working with conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is supposed in an element with a default phrase if it is empty for a period of time. It works if i make a seperate if statement for every element but doesn't work when I try to combine it in one statement with $(this).

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oojy1ug/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="data-block">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>One</h2></li>
        <li><h2></h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="data-block">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>Two</h2></li>
        <li><h2></h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="data-block">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>Three</h2></li>
        <li><h2></h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if ($.trim($(".datablock li:last-child h2").html()) == '') {
        $(this).text('Not Applicable');
    };
}, 1500);
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `this` to refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setTimeout` context `this` always refers to browser object and you had typo `.datablock`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $ele = $(".data-block li:last-child h2");
    if ($.trim($ele.html()) == '') {
        $ele.text('Not Applicable');
    };
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
 if ($.trim($(".data-block li:last-child h2").html()) == '') {
    $(".data-block li:last-child h2").text('Not Applicable');
  };
}, 1500);
```